# variables en (document.getElementById)

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una función para enviar el id de una celda, y poder cambiar su valor.
No consigo que funcione....

```
function editar(idObjeto){
    
    var precio = prompt("Precio para: "+idObjeto);
    var obj = "'"+idObjeto+"'"
    alert(obj)
    
   document.getElementById(obj).innerHTML=precio;   
    
    }
```

evidentemente el problema está en la construcción de la variable, porque si lo hago directamente, funciona bien.

```
document.getElementById('1234').innerHTML=precio; // funciona bien
```

que estoy haciendo mal.???

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes con el primer código?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu HTML? Pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo a la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el HTML? Lo único que podría hacer necesario un código escrito así es una mala práctica. ¿Por qué no usas escuchadores de eventos y obtienes el id del elemento usando el target? Quizá ni siquiera eso sea necesario. Este código no me cuadra en absoluto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás **agregando comillas simples al Id** que buscas.

Por lo tanto está tratando de hacer

```
document.getElementById("'1234'")
```

Y no

```
document.getElementById("1234")
```

Intenta con

```
document.getElementById(idObjeto.toString()).innerHTML=precio
```

Y debería funcionar

Comment: Yo creo que el origen del problema es una mala práctica, tanto en el HTML como en la misma lógica. Eso de tener que pasar el id de un elemento en parámetro a una función es muy extraño cuando existen escuchadores de eventos con los cuales puedes usar el target para identificar al elemento o a sus vecinos si fuera necesario... Así como pedir un precio en un prompt ... Muy raro.

Comment: Concuerdo, usar los `id` es no pasar por el usuario para manipular los elementos, lo cuál deja al usuario por fuera, lo cuál no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Tampoco se considera una buena práctica utilizar `id` numéricos, por ejemplo: `id="123"`. De hecho, si se utiliza con `querySelector` se produce un error indicando que no es un **selector válido**. Puede leer sbre  [el atributo `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) para conocer un poco más sobre el tema.

Answer (score 4):

Pedí el HTML de tu código porque estoy casi seguro de que hay malas prácticas en él, por ejemplo, en JS se recomienda no usar funciones in-line<sup>1</sup>. Puede que `editar()` esté siendo llamado desde  un elemento HTML (in-line).

Se recomienda además usar escuchadores de eventos, **precisamente para este caso concreto facilitan enormemente el trabajo**, porque podrías usar el target para obtener el valor que te interesa, **sin tener que pasarlo en parámetro a la función**. Y puedes usar el target también para alcanzar/modificar elementos contiguos, sean del tipo que sean, Javascript tiene varios métodos para este tipo de alcance.

Veamos un ejemplo, aquí la función se lanzará cuando presiones en cualquiera de los botones, y el precio escrito en el Prompt se escribirá tanto en un `span` que hay antes de cada botón, como en el `input` contiguo al mismo botón. Simplemente imagino tu escenario, y le busco un poco de sentido. Si no es de este modo lo puedes cambiar si has entendido los conceptos. Si se trata de modificar algún atributo del mismo elemento (en este caso el botón), también es posible con `e.target`. Y si se trata de otro elemento diferente de un `input`, lo mismo, lo puedes alcanzar mediante `e.target`  y modificarlo. Todo es cuestión de organizar tu contenido HTML de una forma lógica.

Con esta práctica, tu código HTML no es dependiente del código Javascript. Si tú escribes funciones in-line, y el código evoluciona, tendrás que ir a buscar las decenas, centenas o miles de HTML donde usaste esa función in-line, para cambiarla ...

```js
/*Seleccionamos todos los botones dentro del div con la clase price*/
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll("div.price button");

/*Asignamos un listener a TODOS los botones antes seleccionados*/
allButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    /*Nótese el uso de e.target, tanto para
      determinar el id del botón presionado
      como para encontrar el input contiguo
    */
    var precio = prompt(`Precio para: ${e.target.id}`);
 
    let prev=e.target.previousElementSibling;
    prev.textContent=precio;
    let next = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    next.value = precio;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <span></span><button id="btn1">Fijar precio 1</button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Aqui verás el precio 1" />
  <hr />
  <span></span><button id="btn2">Fijar precio 2</button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Aqui verás el precio 2" />  
  <hr />
  <span></span><button id="btn3">Fijar precio 3</button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Aqui verás el precio 3" />  
</div>
```

---

#### Notas

1. Leer al respecto el apartado [*Separation of structure and behaviour* (*Separación de estructura y comportamiento*)](https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript), en w3.org